# Automatically space internal node from leaf in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I am new to d3 and I've been playing with the [cluster diagram example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339607) but quickly I realized that the example works great for short labels and small clusters.

When applied to my data I realized I have a couple of issues :

- internal node labels can be long (this causes the labels to overlap children nodes
- nodes are not distant depending on the label lengths (is this actually possible to do ?

I succeeded to wrap the labels of the node using the code below

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is also it wraps the labels of the leaf nodes (which is not what am aiming for)

my code is pretty much the same as the example above

```
var radius = 900 / 2;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, radius - 120]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", radius * 2)
    .attr("height", radius * 2)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

d3.json("img/fullstack.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);

  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(cluster.links(nodes))
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2)

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .call(wrap, 100 );
    });
```

and the results is not that clean

[image]

Is it possible to

- wrap only internal nodes ?
- make the nodes dynamically distant to the child node depending on the label content ?

Any suggestion is welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have resolved this issue by adding ellipsis and tool-tips to the overflowing text for the internal nodes. Hope this helps.

**Sample Code:**

```
var labels = node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".31em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

var internalNodes = labels.filter(function(d) {   
    return (d.children != undefined)
  });

internalNodes.each(wrap);

internalNodes.append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  });

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", radius * 2 + "px");

function wrap() {
   var width = 60;
   var self = d3.select(this),
       textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
       text = self.text();
   while (textLength > (width - 2) && text.length > 0) {
     text = text.slice(0, -1);
     self.text(text + '...');
     textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
   }
}
```

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var radius = 960 / 2;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
  .size([360, radius - 120]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", radius * 2)
  .attr("height", radius * 2)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

var root = {
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [{
    "name": "analytics",
    "children": [{
      "name": "cluster cluster cluster cluster cluster",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "CommunityStructure",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "MergeEdge",
        "size": 743
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "graph graph graph graph graph graph",
      "children": [{
        "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
        "size": 3534
      }, {
        "name": "LinkDistance",
        "size": 5731
      }, {
        "name": "MaxFlowMinCut",
        "size": 7840
      }, {
        "name": "ShortestPaths",
        "size": 5914
      }, {
        "name": "SpanningTree",
        "size": 3416
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "optimization",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
        "size": 7074
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "animate",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Easing",
      "size": 17010
    }, {
      "name": "FunctionSequence",
      "size": 5842
    }, {
      "name": "interpolate",
      "children": [{
        "name": "ArrayInterpolator",
        "size": 1983
      }, {
        "name": "ColorInterpolator",
        "size": 2047
      }, {
        "name": "DateInterpolator",
        "size": 1375
      }, {
        "name": "Interpolator",
        "size": 8746
      }, {
        "name": "MatrixInterpolator",
        "size": 2202
      }, {
        "name": "NumberInterpolator",
        "size": 1382
      }, {
        "name": "ObjectInterpolator",
        "size": 1629
      }, {
        "name": "PointInterpolator",
        "size": 1675
      }, {
        "name": "RectangleInterpolator",
        "size": 2042
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "ISchedulable",
      "size": 1041
    }, {
      "name": "Parallel",
      "size": 5176
    }, {
      "name": "Pause",
      "size": 449
    }, {
      "name": "Scheduler",
      "size": 5593
    }, {
      "name": "Sequence",
      "size": 5534
    }, {
      "name": "Transition",
      "size": 9201
    }, {
      "name": "Transitioner",
      "size": 19975
    }, {
      "name": "TransitionEvent",
      "size": 1116
    }, {
      "name": "Tween",
      "size": 6006
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "data",
    "children": [{
      "name": "converters",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Converters",
        "size": 721
      }, {
        "name": "DelimitedTextConverter",
        "size": 4294
      }, {
        "name": "GraphMLConverter",
        "size": 9800
      }, {
        "name": "IDataConverter",
        "size": 1314
      }, {
        "name": "JSONConverter",
        "size": 2220
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "DataField",
      "size": 1759
    }, {
      "name": "DataSchema",
      "size": 2165
    }, {
      "name": "DataSet",
      "size": 586
    }, {
      "name": "DataSource",
      "size": 3331
    }, {
      "name": "DataTable",
      "size": 772
    }, {
      "name": "DataUtil",
      "size": 3322
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "display",
    "children": [{
      "name": "DirtySprite",
      "size": 8833
    }, {
      "name": "LineSprite",
      "size": 1732
    }, {
      "name": "RectSprite",
      "size": 3623
    }, {
      "name": "TextSprite",
      "size": 10066
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "flex",
    "children": [{
      "name": "FlareVis",
      "size": 4116
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "physics",
    "children": [{
      "name": "DragForce",
      "size": 1082
    }, {
      "name": "GravityForce",
      "size": 1336
    }, {
      "name": "IForce",
      "size": 319
    }, {
      "name": "NBodyForce",
      "size": 10498
    }, {
      "name": "Particle",
      "size": 2822
    }, {
      "name": "Simulation",
      "size": 9983
    }, {
      "name": "Spring",
      "size": 2213
    }, {
      "name": "SpringForce",
      "size": 1681
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "query",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AggregateExpression",
      "size": 1616
    }, {
      "name": "And",
      "size": 1027
    }, {
      "name": "Arithmetic",
      "size": 3891
    }, {
      "name": "Average",
      "size": 891
    }, {
      "name": "BinaryExpression",
      "size": 2893
    }, {
      "name": "Comparison",
      "size": 5103
    }, {
      "name": "CompositeExpression",
      "size": 3677
    }, {
      "name": "Count",
      "size": 781
    }, {
      "name": "DateUtil",
      "size": 4141
    }, {
      "name": "Distinct",
      "size": 933
    }, {
      "name": "Expression",
      "size": 5130
    }, {
      "name": "ExpressionIterator",
      "size": 3617
    }, {
      "name": "Fn",
      "size": 3240
    }, {
      "name": "If",
      "size": 2732
    }, {
      "name": "IsA",
      "size": 2039
    }, {
      "name": "Literal",
      "size": 1214
    }, {
      "name": "Match",
      "size": 3748
    }, {
      "name": "Maximum",
      "size": 843
    }, {
      "name": "methods",
      "children": [{
        "name": "add",
        "size": 593
      }, {
        "name": "and",
        "size": 330
      }, {
        "name": "average",
        "size": 287
      }, {
        "name": "count",
        "size": 277
      }, {
        "name": "distinct",
        "size": 292
      }, {
        "name": "div",
        "size": 595
      }, {
        "name": "eq",
        "size": 594
      }, {
        "name": "fn",
        "size": 460
      }, {
        "name": "gt",
        "size": 603
      }, {
        "name": "gte",
        "size": 625
      }, {
        "name": "iff",
        "size": 748
      }, {
        "name": "isa",
        "size": 461
      }, {
        "name": "lt",
        "size": 597
      }, {
        "name": "lte",
        "size": 619
      }, {
        "name": "max",
        "size": 283
      }, {
        "name": "min",
        "size": 283
      }, {
        "name": "mod",
        "size": 591
      }, {
        "name": "mul",
        "size": 603
      }, {
        "name": "neq",
        "size": 599
      }, {
        "name": "not",
        "size": 386
      }, {
        "name": "or",
        "size": 323
      }, {
        "name": "orderby",
        "size": 307
      }, {
        "name": "range",
        "size": 772
      }, {
        "name": "select",
        "size": 296
      }, {
        "name": "stddev",
        "size": 363
      }, {
        "name": "sub",
        "size": 600
      }, {
        "name": "sum",
        "size": 280
      }, {
        "name": "update",
        "size": 307
      }, {
        "name": "variance",
        "size": 335
      }, {
        "name": "where",
        "size": 299
      }, {
        "name": "xor",
        "size": 354
      }, {
        "name": "_",
        "size": 264
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Minimum",
      "size": 843
    }, {
      "name": "Not",
      "size": 1554
    }, {
      "name": "Or",
      "size": 970
    }, {
      "name": "Query",
      "size": 13896
    }, {
      "name": "Range",
      "size": 1594
    }, {
      "name": "StringUtil",
      "size": 4130
    }, {
      "name": "Sum",
      "size": 791
    }, {
      "name": "Variable",
      "size": 1124
    }, {
      "name": "Variance",
      "size": 1876
    }, {
      "name": "Xor",
      "size": 1101
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "scale",
    "children": [{
      "name": "IScaleMap",
      "size": 2105
    }, {
      "name": "LinearScale",
      "size": 1316
    }, {
      "name": "LogScale",
      "size": 3151
    }, {
      "name": "OrdinalScale",
      "size": 3770
    }, {
      "name": "QuantileScale",
      "size": 2435
    }, {
      "name": "QuantitativeScale",
      "size": 4839
    }, {
      "name": "RootScale",
      "size": 1756
    }, {
      "name": "Scale",
      "size": 4268
    }, {
      "name": "ScaleType",
      "size": 1821
    }, {
      "name": "TimeScale",
      "size": 5833
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "util",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Arrays",
      "size": 8258
    }, {
      "name": "Colors",
      "size": 10001
    }, {
      "name": "Dates",
      "size": 8217
    }, {
      "name": "Displays",
      "size": 12555
    }, {
      "name": "Filter",
      "size": 2324
    }, {
      "name": "Geometry",
      "size": 10993
    }, {
      "name": "heap",
      "children": [{
        "name": "FibonacciHeap",
        "size": 9354
      }, {
        "name": "HeapNode",
        "size": 1233
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "IEvaluable",
      "size": 335
    }, {
      "name": "IPredicate",
      "size": 383
    }, {
      "name": "IValueProxy",
      "size": 874
    }, {
      "name": "math",
      "children": [{
        "name": "DenseMatrix",
        "size": 3165
      }, {
        "name": "IMatrix",
        "size": 2815
      }, {
        "name": "SparseMatrix",
        "size": 3366
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Maths",
      "size": 17705
    }, {
      "name": "Orientation",
      "size": 1486
    }, {
      "name": "palette",
      "children": [{
        "name": "ColorPalette",
        "size": 6367
      }, {
        "name": "Palette",
        "size": 1229
      }, {
        "name": "ShapePalette",
        "size": 2059
      }, {
        "name": "SizePalette",
        "size": 2291
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Property",
      "size": 5559
    }, {
      "name": "Shapes",
      "size": 19118
    }, {
      "name": "Sort",
      "size": 6887
    }, {
      "name": "Stats",
      "size": 6557
    }, {
      "name": "Strings",
      "size": 22026
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "vis",
    "children": [{
      "name": "axis",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Axes",
        "size": 1302
      }, {
        "name": "Axis",
        "size": 24593
      }, {
        "name": "AxisGridLine",
        "size": 652
      }, {
        "name": "AxisLabel",
        "size": 636
      }, {
        "name": "CartesianAxes",
        "size": 6703
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "controls",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AnchorControl",
        "size": 2138
      }, {
        "name": "ClickControl",
        "size": 3824
      }, {
        "name": "Control",
        "size": 1353
      }, {
        "name": "ControlList",
        "size": 4665
      }, {
        "name": "DragControl",
        "size": 2649
      }, {
        "name": "ExpandControl",
        "size": 2832
      }, {
        "name": "HoverControl",
        "size": 4896
      }, {
        "name": "IControl",
        "size": 763
      }, {
        "name": "PanZoomControl",
        "size": 5222
      }, {
        "name": "SelectionControl",
        "size": 7862
      }, {
        "name": "TooltipControl",
        "size": 8435
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "data",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Data",
        "size": 20544
      }, {
        "name": "DataList",
        "size": 19788
      }, {
        "name": "DataSprite",
        "size": 10349
      }, {
        "name": "EdgeSprite",
        "size": 3301
      }, {
        "name": "NodeSprite",
        "size": 19382
      }, {
        "name": "render",
        "children": [{
          "name": "ArrowType",
          "size": 698
        }, {
          "name": "EdgeRenderer",
          "size": 5569
        }, {
          "name": "IRenderer",
          "size": 353
        }, {
          "name": "ShapeRenderer",
          "size": 2247
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "ScaleBinding",
        "size": 11275
      }, {
        "name": "Tree",
        "size": 7147
      }, {
        "name": "TreeBuilder",
        "size": 9930
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "events",
      "children": [{
        "name": "DataEvent",
        "size": 2313
      }, {
        "name": "SelectionEvent",
        "size": 1880
      }, {
        "name": "TooltipEvent",
        "size": 1701
      }, {
        "name": "VisualizationEvent",
        "size": 1117
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "legend",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Legend",
        "size": 20859
      }, {
        "name": "LegendItem",
        "size": 4614
      }, {
        "name": "LegendRange",
        "size": 10530
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "operator",
      "children": [{
        "name": "distortion",
        "children": [{
          "name": "BifocalDistortion",
          "size": 4461
        }, {
          "name": "Distortion",
          "size": 6314
        }, {
          "name": "FisheyeDistortion",
          "size": 3444
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "encoder",
        "children": [{
          "name": "ColorEncoder",
          "size": 3179
        }, {
          "name": "Encoder",
          "size": 4060
        }, {
          "name": "PropertyEncoder",
          "size": 4138
        }, {
          "name": "ShapeEncoder",
          "size": 1690
        }, {
          "name": "SizeEncoder",
          "size": 1830
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "filter",
        "children": [{
          "name": "FisheyeTreeFilter",
          "size": 5219
        }, {
          "name": "GraphDistanceFilter",
          "size": 3165
        }, {
          "name": "VisibilityFilter",
          "size": 3509
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "IOperator",
        "size": 1286
      }, {
        "name": "label",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Labeler",
          "size": 9956
        }, {
          "name": "RadialLabeler",
          "size": 3899
        }, {
          "name": "StackedAreaLabeler",
          "size": 3202
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "layout",
        "children": [{
          "name": "AxisLayout",
          "size": 6725
        }, {
          "name": "BundledEdgeRouter",
          "size": 3727
        }, {
          "name": "CircleLayout",
          "size": 9317
        }, {
          "name": "CirclePackingLayout",
          "size": 12003
        }, {
          "name": "DendrogramLayout",
          "size": 4853
        }, {
          "name": "ForceDirectedLayout",
          "size": 8411
        }, {
          "name": "IcicleTreeLayout",
          "size": 4864
        }, {
          "name": "IndentedTreeLayout",
          "size": 3174
        }, {
          "name": "Layout",
          "size": 7881
        }, {
          "name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout",
          "size": 12870
        }, {
          "name": "PieLayout",
          "size": 2728
        }, {
          "name": "RadialTreeLayout",
          "size": 12348
        }, {
          "name": "RandomLayout",
          "size": 870
        }, {
          "name": "StackedAreaLayout",
          "size": 9121
        }, {
          "name": "TreeMapLayout",
          "size": 9191
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Operator",
        "size": 2490
      }, {
        "name": "OperatorList",
        "size": 5248
      }, {
        "name": "OperatorSequence",
        "size": 4190
      }, {
        "name": "OperatorSwitch",
        "size": 2581
      }, {
        "name": "SortOperator",
        "size": 2023
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Visualization",
      "size": 16540
    }]
  }]
};


var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);

var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
  .data(cluster.links(nodes))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", diagonal);

var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
  })

node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4.5);

var labels = node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".31em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

var internalNodes = labels.filter(function(d) {
  return (d.children != undefined)
});

internalNodes.each(wrap);

internalNodes.append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  });

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", radius * 2 + "px");

function wrap() {
  var width = 60;
  var self = d3.select(this),
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
    text = self.text();
  while (textLength > (width - 2) && text.length > 0) {
    text = text.slice(0, -1);
    self.text(text + '...');
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
  }
}
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Gilsha for your input. Elegant solution, only problem it truncates the labels which make them hard to read, will try to wrap instead of truncate